# react set new object in array only setting lat item in map

Tags: reactjs, state

I am trying to set state dynamically in order to create column headers for my reactTable. As I loop through my object to get properties for my header field I want to add the new column to the columns array in state, but its only adding the last item in the object array to the columns array. I'm cloning the state before  setting it with the new column, but I'm obviously missing something. Thanks in advance.

```
class ExpandedReactTable extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        /*state values are dynamic*/
        this.state = {
            columns: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(actions.getProjectedDataList());
    }

/*Just pulling the first object from the array and getting the field names - these field names will be set as the column headers in the table*/

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (prevProps.dataList !== this.props.dataList && this.props.dataList.length > 0) {
            Object.keys(this.props.dataList[0]).map(key => {
                this.setState({ [key]: true }); //this is getting set correctly

//now - set each column object in state.
//at this end, the columns state only has the last object that was mapped over
                this.setState({
                    columns: [...this.state.columns,
                    {
                        Header: [key, <br />, <input type="checkbox" name={key} checked={this.state[key]} onChange={(e) => this.updateColumnShow(key)} />],
                        accessor: key,
                        show: true
                    }]
                })
            })
        }
    }
```

I should end up with 7 objects in the columns array but only end up with the last object being mapped over:

```
columns [{Header: :{object}, accessor: value, show: boolean}],
```

Comment: The call to `this.setState()` updates state asynchronously. So when you call `this.setState()` a second time, the value of `[key]` has not yet been set to `true` in your state.

Comment: Where is `this.state.columns` used. Do the columns really need to be stored in state? Or should you just create this on the fly during `render()`?

Comment: `Do the columns really need to be stored in state? ` - valid question - I had hoped not, however when I try to access them as props in the react table I haven't been able to do so. If you have a suggestion for how to do that w/o needing to set them in state I'm open

Comment: I assume that you use `this.state.columns` in `render()`. If that is the case, then you could just generate them directly in render with something like `const columns = Object.keys(this.props.dataList[0]).map()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since setState is async you have to use prevState of setState like this:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.dataList !== this.props.dataList && this.props.dataList.length > 0) {
        Object.keys(this.props.dataList[0]).map(key => {
            this.setState({ [key]: true }); //this is getting set correctly

            this.setState(prevState => {
                columns: [...prevState columns,
                {
                    Header: [key, <br />, <input type="checkbox" name={key} checked={this.state[key]} onChange={(e) => this.updateColumnShow(key)} />],
                    accessor: key,
                    show: true
                }]
            })
        })
    }
}
```

The state is not updated while you call the loop. PrevState will be the previous set state and this should work.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but my state doesn't appear to be getting set at all this way

Comment: @rralbritton So I created this [codepen](https://codepen.io/Domino987/pen/jONwQNo?editors=1111) as a proof of concept and that only works with prevState.

Comment: Thank you @ Domino - I had to modify it for my use case but it did work. Moving everything into the setColumn function and calling it from componentDIdUpdate works